# Is it possible to create a correct SPF and DMARC DNS record when you use a CNAME?

Tags: heroku, sendgrid, spf, dmarc

In my setup I have a website (example.app) hosted on Heroku.

Then, I use Sendgrid to send emails from the Heroku server to our users that forget their password. The email is registered using Google's Gsuite. So I also send emails from the Google servers.

The from email is: `<Appname <noreply@example.app>`

So I thought these should be my DNS records (note I don't have an A-record):

CNAMES:

`example.app CNAME "example.app.herokudns.com"
www.example.app CNAME "www.example.app.herokudns.com"`

SPF:

`example.app TXT "v=spf1 a include:_spf.google.com include:sendgrid.net ~all"`

Dmarc:

`_dmarc TXT v=DMARC1; p=none; rua=mailto:dmarc@example.app; ruf=mailto:dmarc-forensic@example.app; fo=0; adkim=r; aspf=r; rf=afrf; pct=100; ri=86400; sp=none`

However, the Dmarc record doesn't validate as mail is send from a different domain then the To address. I think the email is send from sendgrid.com and the to-address is example.app.

Hence, I think by adding the IP-addresses of my Heroku DNS into the SPF record it should work.

But how do I do this, when these IP-addresses are dynamic?

Comment: CNAMEs are resolved first, so your SPF record is unreachable.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by that @Synchro ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"No" [by protocol - rfc1912#section-2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1912#section-2.4) but "yes" if using [CNAME flattening.](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169056-CNAME-Flattening-RFC-compliant-support-for-CNAME-at-the-root)

Also, you should configure your [SPF](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Glossary/spf.html) and DMARC using your email servers, in your case, `sendgrid` not `your@example.app`

Check more about how Cloudflare deals with CNAME flattening here:  https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cname-flattening-rfc-compliant-cnames-at-a-domains-root/

Comment: Thank you it works now!

I use CNAME flattening on my DNS (feature of Cloudflare).
That way I can use the A record in my SPF record, while not having an A-record specified. Because Cloudflare "mimics" an A-record based on the C-name.

Also I setup Sendgrid's Authentication headers using this documentation:
https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/Sender_authentication/How_to_set_up_domain_authentication.html