# How to configure DNS on Heroku (pointdns)

Tags: heroku, dns

I have the following configuration in pointDNS:

```
* SOA example.com dnsx.pointhq.com, admin.xxx.com, ...
* ALIAS example.com xxx.herokussl.com.
* CNAME www.example.com. xxx.herokussl.com. (same as above)
* NX example.com dnsx.xxx.com (same as above)
* NX example.com dnsy.pointhq.com (different)
```

I did not make this initial configuration and now trying to understand what this means.

The main issue is the fact when we visit `example.com` we are redirected to `https://example.com` and when we visit `www.example.com` we're redirected to `https://www.example.com`.

How can I solve this in the configuration above?

Comment: What is the exact issue?

Comment: I want that everything is redirected to https://www.example.com. The issue is the fact that when I visit example.com I got redirected to https://example.com instead of https://www.example.com. I hope you understand? (http to https redirect is working fine, but url not)

Comment: Your DNS provider should have the service to redirect a root (apex) domain to www or https. Otherwise you need to have a server to accept the root domain https request and than in request header redirect to www.

Comment: I don't fully understand, but so just changing some configuration described above won't be enough?

Answer (score 1):

In case you would also like to [receive/send email](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51323836/1135424) using your custom domain, probably the easiest way would be to use Cloudflare, check Heroku docs for: [Configuring DNS for root domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#configuring-dns-for-root-domains)

Within Cloudflare to redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com` you could create a [Page rule](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-How-do-I-perform-URL-forwarding-or-redirects-with-Cloudflare-):

```
example.com/*
```

You'd then setup the following URL for traffic to forward to:

```
https://www.example.com/$1
```

To do the redirect with PointDNS you will have to delete first the Alias:

[image]

Then click on the redirect icon and don't type any name:
[image]

If you haven't delete the **ALIAS** record you will get the warning shown in the picture

[image]

Once you create the redirect it should look like this:

[image]

**Common Runtime - SSL Endpoint**

> If you’re using the SSL Endpoint, note that your DNS Targets will be a little different. For apps in the Common Runtime, the endpoint domain name will vary depending on region. The US region will have a name in the form of example-2121.herokussl.com. Apps in the EU region will have the same domain name as your app’s herokuapp domain, e.g. my-app-name.herokuapp.com.

Comment: and do you know how this works for pointdns? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pointdns

Comment: Cool; I'll try! Are those changes executed immediatly or do I have to wait one hour with TTL 3600?

Comment: @DenCowboy I don't think you will have to wait for the redirect, give a try

Comment: I can only give the bounty in 18 hours. I've implemented it but it seems I have to wait for 1 hour now (read it)

Comment: @DenCowboy in any case you could also use cloudflare I think is easier

Comment: Everything works with the redirect except I'm facing a NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error when go to https://www.example.com (going to http://www.example.com redirects fine)

Comment: Do I need to transfer my domain in some way first? My domain entry on PointDNS has status "red". I also have DNS entries in AWS Route 53, I found a way to export them, but I'm not sure if I need to transfer my domain name or something

Comment: @CQM: No you don't need to transfer your domain if you are using services like pointDNS.